# quantregForest x contains no data

Tags: r

Running this code:

```
library(datasets)
library(quantregForest)

Xtrain <- iris$Sepal.Length
Ytrain <- iris$Petal.Width

model <- quantregForest(
    x = Xtrain
    , y = Ytrain
)
```

but get this error message:

```
Error in quantregForest(x = Xtrain, y = Ytrain) :  x contains no data
```

Can anyone see what's wrong please?

PS:

This works though:

```
library(datasets)
library(quantregForest)
library(dplyr)

Xtrain <- iris %>%
    select(
        Sepal.Length
        , Petal.Length
    )

Ytrain <- iris$Petal.Width

model <- quantregForest(
    x = Xtrain
    , y = Ytrain
)
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in quantregForest whihc use nrow instead of NROW to check for this error message ...

Comment: `?quantregForest` says that `x` should be a matrix or dataframe. You have passed a vector. Try with `Xtrain <- iris["Sepal.Length"]`. But yes, not a very helpful error message

Comment: close vote - why?!

Comment: Hi cs0815 ; I voted to close this as the [problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as I thought it seemed little more than a typo, -- happy to retract if you disagree

Comment: Maybe read this again ?

Comment: In terms of reproducibility simply run code ...

Comment: Yes, your code was reproducible, and that allowed me to give you the solution. However, the error in your code was so minimal -- I voted to close as after this minor correction  the error cannot be reproduced, and in *my* opinion it fell into the " unlikely to help future readers". But retracted my vote -- no point annoying you.